# bitbucket hook for automatic update of source code from branch

Tags: bitbucket, git-pull, git

I have a repo named Live and 2 branches master and livecloud.
Now I want to add a hook to update source code from bitbucket branch livecloud only as soon as commit is pushed in this branch.

code in hook.php

```
    <?php
echo "Begin: Pull code from BitBucket<br/>";
exec('git pull', $output);
foreach ($output as $o) {
    echo $o . '<br/>';
}
echo "End: Pull code from BitBucket<br/>";
```

this shows a request in webhooks with a response body but the source code files are not updated as per the changes committed in the branch.

Comment: See Git "hooks" -  actions that be executed after other actions. See the post-receive hook. But, on my opinion auto-pull is bed idea - if somebody make commit with error you will get it in your local code!. Please reread Git book again about git workflow.

Comment: @EmbeddedDev I am still a newbie to bitbucket and git can you please expain in detail what I need to do here. Thanks